# how to add an element and don't lost de style

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new in JQuery Mobile, and I'm trying to do a list of elements and its atributes.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              var text = '{"productes":[' +
              '{"Nom":"Lays","Tipus":"Patata","Categoria":"Aliments","PreuCompra":"0,35","PreuVenda":"1","Comprar":"S&iacute;","Vendre":"S&iacute;","UdM":"kg" },' +
              '{"Nom":"Magdalenes","Tipus":"Pasta","Categoria":"Aliment","PreuCompra":"1","PreuVenda":"1.25","Comprar":"No","Vendre":"S&iacute","UdM":"kg" },' +
              '{"Nom":"Espaguetis Gallina Blanca","Tipus":"Pasta","Categoria":"Aiment","PreuCompra":"0,40","PreuVenda":"1,30","Comprar":"S&iacute;","Vendre":"S&iacute","UdM":"gr" },' +
              '{"Nom":"Fairy","Tipus":"Rentabaixelles","Categoria":"Neteja","PreuCompra":"0,40","PreuVenda":"1,30","Comprar":"No","Vendre":"S&iacute;","UdM":"ml" }]}';


var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(text);
              for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        $("#llista").append("<div data-role='collapsible'> <h3>"+ obj.productes[i].Nom +"</h3> <p>Tipus: "+ obj.productes[i].Tipus + "<br>Categoria: " + obj.productes[i].Categoria +"<br>Preu compra: " + obj.productes[i].PreuCompra +"&euro;<br>Preu Venda: " + obj.productes[i].PreuVenda +"&euro;<br>Comprar: " + obj.productes[i].Comprar +"<br>Vendre: " + obj.productes[i].Vendre +"<br>UdM: " + obj.productes[i].UdM +"</p><button data-inline='true'>Eliminar</button><button data-inline='true'>Editar</button></div>");
    }
    $("#nou").click(function(){
         $("#llista").append("<div data-role='collapsible'> <h3>"+ obj.productes[0].Nom +"</h3> <p>Tipus: "+ obj.productes[0].Tipus + "<br>Categoria: " + obj.productes[0].Categoria +"<br>Preu compra: " + obj.productes[0].PreuCompra +"&euro;<br>Preu Venda: " + obj.productes[0].PreuVenda +"&euro;<br>Comprar: " + obj.productes[0].Comprar +"<br>Vendre: " + obj.productes[0].Vendre +"<br>UdM: " + obj.productes[0].UdM +"</p><button id='elim' data-inline='true'>Eliminar</button><button id='edit' data-inline='true'>Editar</button></div>");
    });
```

});

When I click in "Nou element" (New element). It seems that the styles desapear. I don't understand

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming #llista is a collapsibleset div, just call enhanceWithin() after appending the collapsibles: $("#llista").append(...).enhanceWithin();  Also instead of $(document).ready(function(){... use the jQM $(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageid", function(){...

Comment: Post an answer @ezanker ;)

Comment: @Omar, OK, find the answer below ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming #llista is a collapsibleset div, just call **[.enhanceWithin()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)** after appending the collapsibles:

```
$("#llista").append(...).enhanceWithin();
```

This instructs jQM to enhance all the content of the container div including the newly added items.

Also instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){...
```

use the jQM events

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageid", function(){...
```

@Omar has written a wonderful article on page events that can be found here:

http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/